# How to print the position

Tags: bash

How to write the below lines using array??

```
val1=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $1}')   
val2=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $2}') 
val3=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $3}') 
val4=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $4}')
```

Threadout.txt contains like "Thread 1/1/25/100"

Comment: awk command is not working

Comment: What is the awk command?

Comment: val1=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $1}')
val2=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $2}')
val3=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $3}')
val4=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $4}') How to write in array to write in 1 command instead of above 4 lines.??

Comment: What are the contents of Threadout.txt? Could you give a sample? [edit] the question, don't add it in the comments.

Comment: Threadout.txt contains like "Thread 1/1/25/100"

Comment: All information should be in the question, not in the comments. Please use edit.

Comment: Actually i want in array instead of write 4 lines.

Comment: Please fix your question. You have some inconsistencies  `Thread` vs `test`  and `Threadout.txt` vs `File.txt` . In the question you create variables `val1` to `val4`, but in the comment you say you want an array? what now?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.Please ignore all.Now how can i write the below line in array.val1=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $1}')   
val2=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $2}') 
val3=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $3}') 
val4=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $4}')

Comment: *All information should be in the question, not in the comments. Please use edit.*

Comment: @DastageerUmar Please **[edit]** the question to add new information!

Comment: Any Suggestion?

Comment: for((i=1;i<5;i++))
do
val[i]=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $[i]}')
echo $val[i]
done

I have tried this array but not giving the correct result like 1 1 25 100 values .Any error?

Comment: Lack of information here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array using `readarray`:

```
readarray -t val < <(grep -o '[0-9]*' Threadout.txt)
```

Then you can use the array `val`:

```
for v in "${val[@]}"; do
    echo "$v"
done
```

or

```
for k in "${!val[@]}"; do
    echo "${val[$k]}"
done
```

Output:

```
1
1
25
100
```

Comment: Cannot.. becoz my awk printf values are different on all 4 variables

Comment: Which `awk` print ? This is all you need ...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.Please ignore all.Now how can i write the below line in array.val1=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $1}')   
val2=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $2}') 
val3=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $3}') 
val4=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $4}')

Comment: Any Suggestion?

Comment: Hi..I want to finish this task by today.Can anyone help?

Comment: for((i=1;i<5;i++))
do
val[i]=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $[i]}')
echo $val[i]
done

I have tried this array but not giving the correct result like 1 1 25 100 values .Any error?

Comment: Use this solution and `printf '%s\n' "${val[@]}"` or 
`for i in "${val[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done` 
or `for i in "${!val[@]}"; do echo "${val[i]}"; done`.
or `for((i=0;i<${#val[@]};i++)); do echo "${val[i]}"; done`.

Comment: Ok.But Kindly see my awk -F print variables and values are different. Currently not printing.How to achieve ?

Comment: What has your `awk` thing to do with it? My answer does not need `awk`, it's complete without anything else.

Comment: Problem resolved.Thanks a lot.