# Print values in Array Bash Script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

My file `Threadout.txt` contains like `Thread 1/1/25/100`

```
val1=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $1}')  
val2=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $2}')    
val3=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $3}')  
val4=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $4}')

for((i=1;i<5;i++))  
do  
  val[i]=$(grep 'Thread' Threadout.txt | awk -F"/" '{print $[i]}')  
  echo $val[i] 
done
```

I have tried this array but not giving the correct result like `1 1 25 100` values. Any error?

Comment: Please give a complete example of the content of `Threadout.txt`. Does it really only contain the line `Thread 1/1/25/100`?

Comment: Please don't post the same question again, rather improve your first question to get answers there --> [How to print the position](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631018/how-to-print-the-position). Especially I still don't understand what is your problem with my answer which seem to exactly do what you expect.

Comment: @DastageerUmar Do you get any output or error when you run the script? If so, could you please add them to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

- The first important thing to remember is that since your `awk` program is enclosed in single quotes (which is recommended), no shell parameter expansions take place, and your statement `print $[i]` will not work. See this [exhaustive Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/12231187) on how to use shell parameter in `awk` programs.
- Even so, an `awk` field whose number is stored in a (`awk`) variable `n` would be addressed via `$n`, not `$[n]`.
- You assign the variables `val1` to `val4` but never actually use them, so the first part of your script example doesn't do anything.
- Finally, to dereference an array variable, you have to state `${val[i]}`, not `$val[i]` (which would print the content of the variable `$val`- the empty string - followed by the fixed string `[i]`).

There are also several inefficiencies such as the repeated call to `awk` and (as far as I can tell) a failure to address the issue of the leading `Thread` in your example input when using just `/` as field separator.

To address these issues, and since the relevant values do not contain whitespace in your example, try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

val=( $(awk '/^Thread/{n=split($2,a,/\//); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf("%s%s",a[i],OFS)}' Threadout.txt) )

for i in ${!val[@]}
do
    echo "${val[i]}"
done
```

- The `awk` call will split the second "field" of the line `Thread 1/1/25/100`, namely the `1/1/25/100` part at the `/` into the array `a` and print all entries of the array, separated by `OFS` (which defaults to space).
- The shell script will take the output of that `awk` program and - since it is a space-separated list of tokens - assign the individual tokens to an array variable `val` via the `val=(  ... )` statement.
- It will then iterate over the array indices and print the array values.

You may want to read into bash arrays a little further in the [GNU Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays), or [GreyCat&Lhunath's Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays). I would also recommend you to take a look at [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) to debug your shell scripts.

Comment: you should post this on the original question instead of here.

Comment: @pLumo Heh, you are right, I hadn't seen that one.

Comment: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Comment: @DastageerUmar once again, please state which `awk` version you have installed.

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks a lot and my script is working fine.Now How to assign this each all 4 values  into another variable from this echo ${val[i]}".??Because i need to use the each value into IF condition.Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can use `${val[i]}` the same way as any other shell variable, including its use in test constructs and the like. Otherwiese, just copy it via `newval=${val[1]}` e.g. May I seriously recommend that you look a the tutorials I mentioned in my answer if you want to learn more about shell scripting?